# Visualization of audio files waveform in react native

Tags: react-native, audiowaveform

I have searched a lot and tried so many things but still couldn't find a way to visualize audio in react native. I want something like this

[image]

The only existing package `react-native-audiowaveform` keeps making the build fail with this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-audiowaveform:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-audiowaveform:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find recyclerview-1.0.0.jar (androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/recyclerview/recyclerview/1.0.0/recyclerview-1.0.0.jar
```

Has anyone faced this issue? Also, I would really appreciate other implementation recommendations.